# Deleting rows with formulas - sheets using formulas use new copy and paste information

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a day to day trucking planner with a data sheet. The data sheet is editable and provides the information for the "calendar page" which is protected and cannot be edited.

This is an example of the calendar sheet:

```
 Monday                     Tuesday     
 8/19/2019                  8/20/2019       
 Deana's    1535            Modern Day       4227   
 Acer 5     1631            Metal Works      2001   
 Scottie    2255            Pros Unlimited   2740   
                            All Test Systems 2166   
                            Southwest Air    1676
```

---

These are the formulas I used

```
=TEXT(B2,"dddd")        
=TODAY()        
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A$3), "", Data!$A$3)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C3), "", Data!$C3)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A$4), "", Data!$A$4)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C4), "", Data!$C4)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A$5), "", Data!$A$5)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C5), "", Data!$C5)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A6), "", Data!$A6)    =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C6), "", Data!$C6)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A7), "", Data!$A7)    =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C7), "", Data!$C7)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A8), "", Data!$A8)    =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C8), "", Data!$C8)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A9), "", Data!$A9)    =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C9), "", Data!$C9)    
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A10), "", Data!$A10)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C10), "", Data!$C10)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A11), "", Data!$A11)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C11), "", Data!$C11)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A12), "", Data!$A12)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C12), "", Data!$C12)  



=TEXT(F2,"dddd")        
=WORKDAY(TODAY()+1,0)       
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A14), "", Data!$A14)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C14), "", Data!$C14)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A15), "", Data!$A15)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C15), "", Data!$C15)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A16), "", Data!$A16)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C16), "", Data!$C16)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A17), "", Data!$A17)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C17), "", Data!$C17)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A18), "", Data!$A18)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C18), "", Data!$C18)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A19), "", Data!$A19)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C19), "", Data!$C19)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A20), "", Data!$A20)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C20), "", Data!$C20)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A21), "", Data!$A21)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C21), "", Data!$C21)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A22), "", Data!$A223) =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C22), "", Data!$C22)  
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A23), "", Data!$A23)  =IF(ISBLANK(Data!$C23), "", Data!$C23)
```

---

This is the data sheet

```
Customer    Order # Weight  City & State
Monday, August 19, 2019         
Deana's         P59043   1,535  Jamestown
Acer 5          P54905   1,631  Greensburg
Scottie         P57303   2,255  Temple

Tuesday, August 20, 2019            
Modern Day      P59157   4,227  Johnstown
Metal Works     P54306   2,001  Harrisonburg
Pros Unlimited  P56992   2,740  Oakland
All Systems     P57001   2,166  Mansfield
Southwest Air   P56905   1,676  Cuddy
```

I want to delete data rows from previous day (Monday) and have the data that becomes the new "A2" (Tuesday) to be listed in that calendar cell. This would be done everyday, as shipments go out I no longer need to see that particular day.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a forum. It's a Q&A site. It's not clear what your question is. There are thousands of ways to do what you are asking. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula could be of use to you:

```
=INDEX(Data!A:A,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"),Data!A:A,0)+1,)
```

to replace any of these formulas

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Data!$A$3), "", Data!$A$3)
```

I have changed this formula from my last answer as I realised adding an if/isblank-statement with a double calculation to filter out blanks makes it long and confusing, you can add that in yourself later if you want. What it does is the following:

Breakdown:

```
=INDEX(Data!A:A,MATCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"),Data!A:A,0)+1,)
```

The Text(today() bit gets todays date and converts it into the "Wednesday, aug 22, 2019" format.
The Match bit finds a match with this freshly generated and formatted date in your data sheet and returns the address. The Index bit takes the address returned by match, and with the +1 bit it returns a value from a row lower. For every number you increase this with, it will get a hit from a lower row.

For the next days you would use:

```
=INDEX(Data!A:A,MATCH(TEXT(WORKDAY(TODAY(),1),"dddd, mmmm dd, yyyy"),Data!A:A,0)+1,)
```

The added Workday(Today(),1) bit adds one workday to your formula, to account for weekends being empty. Increasing the 1 and I'll give you that amount of workdays later.

I hope that this is more comprehensive for you and works for what you need.

Comment: Hi Plutian, I am having trouble understanding the formula. Would you be able to kind of break down each piece and explain what its purpose is? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Feel free to accept my answer (little tick next to it) if it solved your problem. Let me know (or post a new question) if you need any more help!